# mysql select statement as a php array

Tags: php, mysql

I have used the PHP Gantt Class from Github here:

https://github.com/bastianallgeier/gantti

I have a php script which generates a gantt chant from data in a php array:

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array(
  'label' => 'Project 1',
  'start' => '2012-04-20', 
   'end'   => '2012-05-12'
);
$data[] = array(
  'label' => 'Project 2',
  'start' => '2012-04-22', 
  'end'   => '2012-05-22'
);
```

Instead of this I would like to use a mysql database to print out results as arrays with a layout that matches the previous way of loading data:

```
$query=mysql_query("select main_task AS 'label', start, end from tasks") or
die(mysql_error());
// Collect the results
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}

// JSON-encode the response
$json_response = json_encode($arr);

// Return the response
echo $json_response;
```

This is the error response I get:

[{"label":"aris","start":"2012-05-15","end":"2012-07-03"},{"label":"test","start":"2012-06-01","end":"2012-07-03"},{"label":"test1","start":"2012-06-01","end":"2012-08-05"},{"label":"Adams","start":"2012-05-06","end":"2012-06-17"},{"label":"hellooo","start":"2012-07-22","end":"2012-09-05"},{"label":"hello 2","start":"2012-05-11","end":"2012-06-03"}]

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/inse1d/public_html/gantti-master/lib/gantti.php on line 44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do as

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
  $arr[] = array('label'=>$obj->label,'start'=>$obj->start,'end'=>$obj->end);
}
```

And then

```
$json_response = json_encode($arr);
```